# Is it possible to have javadoc ignore all classes that have no documentation?

Tags: javadoc

I'd like to create a javadoc for a large existing codebase that has few javadoc comments, but those that do exist are important. To that end I'd like to have the created documentation only describe those classes that actually have documentation. How do I exclude classes with no javadoc comments in them from javadoc's output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, you can check / uncheck all the classes of which docs should be created under Project > Generate Javadoc

Edit: I don't think javadoc supports that kind of functionality. Another approach would be to write a small Java program which parses all of your existing sources and searches for javadoc specific syntax.

Comment: That requires me to already know what classes have documentation.